# How to get number of vCPU in AWS boto python EC2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, boto

Is there a way to get the number if vCPU (cores) in EC2 instance via boto python api?

My code so far is :

found it in boto3 :

```
import boto3     
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=REGION_NAME)
instance = ec2.Instance(id)
instance.cpu_options.get(u'CoreCount','1')
```

which return's me the physical number of cores , but via htop i can  see that i have twice as VCPU's , is it always be this way ? maybe it has something to do with the number of ThreadsPerCore  ?

Comment: Get instance type,  then follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-optimize-cpu.html

Comment: you can only get the instance type. type is some thing that can be use to identify vcpu information etc

Comment: you are right , in boto3 it's posssible

Comment: Side-note: These days, you should use `boto3` rather than the original `boto`. The old version doesn't have access to the latest services.

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way, requires the latest version of boto3:

```
import boto3
# You may have to update boto3 to get this to work, describe_instance_types is quite new:
# pip install boto3 --upgrade
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

reservations = ec2.describe_instances()['Reservations']
vcpus = 0
for reservation in reservations:
    for instance in reservation['Instances']:
        instance_id = instance['InstanceId']
        instance_type_name = instance['InstanceType']
        instance_type = ec2.describe_instance_types(InstanceTypes=[instance_type_name])
        current_vcpu_count = instance_type['InstanceTypes'][0]['VCpuInfo']['DefaultVCpus']
        print(f'{instance_id} - {instance_type_name} - {current_vcpu_count}')
        vcpus += current_vcpu_count

print(vcpus)
```